# if result of "python3 script.py $parameter" is in file.txt, output parameter,result - how to do this?

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

I want to loop over a directory of files with a name on every line and input that as a query parameter to a python script which queries an SQLite database and some APIs and then outputs a city.

I use this to get a list of cities corresponding to names in the text files:

```
for file in *.txt; do while read -r name; do python3 citysearch.py "$name"; done < "$file"; done
```

Now I want to grep each of the cities (output of the python script) in a huge citynames.txt file and output/save only the names which correspond to a city that is included in the file.

If I just pipe to grep the $name variable is lost.
So I tried it with xargs:

```
for file in *.txt; do while read -r name; do python3 citysearch.py "$name"; done < "$file"; done | xargs -0 -I % sh -c 'if grep -Fxq % /home/citynames.txt; then echo $name, $city; fi' sh
```

but that gives me

```
sh: 2: city1: not found
sh: 3: city2: not found
...
sh: 10: /home/citynames.txt: Permission denied
```

I guess I can not use the $name nor the $city variable in the output after the grep? Can I somehow set global variables in a line of bash that survives pipes?

**Edit:** As @charles-duffy requested, here is a minimal version of the files:

**citysearch.py** which just takes the name as a parameter and adds a "town" to the output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

name = sys.argv[1]
print(str(name) + 'town')
```

**names1.txt** with some names:

```
name1
name12
name13
```

**names2.txt** with some other names:

```
name2
name22
name23
```

**citynames.txt** with the interesting cities:

```
name22town
name22city
```

Now I want to loop over the names*.txt files and get

```
name22, name22town
```

as a result, since name22 is the only name that corresponds to a city that is included in the citynames.txt file.

Comment: What's the form of the output of your `citysearch.py` file?

Comment: ...it's not clear to me what you're actually trying to do here. Providing a test case that people who don't have your Python script would run would make things easier (both to write answers, and to determine whether proposed answers that someone else ran are correct).

Comment: The output of citysearch.py is just a city name, like "Paris". For a test case just imagine that the python script ads a string to the name and that result has to be found in the citynames.txt.

Comment: Would probably be easier and more efficient to output the cities output from the Python script to a separate file and then grep using the file for entries to search for.

Comment: @RamanSailopal That, or use `comm` to merge those two files in one pass.

Comment: Your Python script doesn't write `name1town` / `name2town` / etc to output, it writes `names1.txttown` to output; that is to say, it's appending the `town` suffix **to the filename**, not to the file content.

Comment: If I run the script directly as "python3 citysearch.py bla1" it does indeed output bla1town for me and not a filename. AFAIK sys.argv[0] is the filename and sys.argv[1] the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the buggy Python script given in the question with an equivalent `sed` operation, one gets:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for file in names*.txt; do
  while IFS= read -r name; do
    while IFS= read -r city; do
      echo "$name, $city"
    done < <(sed -e 's/$/town/' <"$file" | grep -Fx -f citynames.txt)
  done < "$file"
done
```

Comment: @riveratheera, see edits -- replacing the Python script with a line of `sed` that lacks the bugs, and using the `-f` argument to `grep` so it's reading lines from `citynames.txt`, instead of _grepping for the exact string_ `citynames.txt`. (Also started searching for `names*.txt` so `citynames.txt` can be in the same directory).

Comment: thanks, but I provided the minimal version of the python script just to make it easy to replicate. I am afraid I can not replace the real python script (which queries an SQLite database and some APIs, as I explained above) with a sed... The python script is out of scope :) As I explained in your other comment, the minimal python script from the example should work if you just run it as  "python3 citysearch.py bla1".

Comment: @riveratheera, yes, but the _provided_ python script sample didn't do what you claimed, and its output was something for which your sample data would never match. Anyhow, I'm not telling you to use `sed` in your real code. I'm asking you to use _something that actually writes real city names to stdout_ in your real code, which the stock Python doesn't do but the `sed` does. If your real Python doesn't have the bug in question, then you can use your real Python without replacing or changing it.